# How to drop tables form oracle 11g recycle bin?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I drop tables (table1,tables2,...) using the

```
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table table_name';
```

That dropped tables have been moved into the database recycle bin so memory didn't release.

Please let me know how I will drop specific table from oracle recycle bin.

Comment: `purge recyclebin` or `drop table purge` details are documented in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9003.htm#SQLRF01806 and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9018.htm#SQLRF01803

Answer (score 4):

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9018.htm

```
purge table table_name;
```

or

```
purge recyclebin; --purge everything
```

or

```
purge dba_recyclebin; -- purge everything for everyone (needs SYSDBA)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers given by `stee1rat` to remove the dropped objects you can also change your code to

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE table_name PURGE';
```

if you want those tables to be deleted permanently without being placed into the recyclebin.

Comment: It's stee1, bro! Doesn't matter, though :)